# Filter two tables using the same filter in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables showing country data in PowerBI, one table contains sales data in different countries and another shows stats about each country. I then have a dashboard that has a chart from each table. I want a single filter that filters on the country column in both tables. 
i.e. If I filter on the US, I will get a chart showing sales data in the  US and a chart showing other stats about the US.

The country columns have duplicate values in both tables so doing a relationship between them is difficult. Moreover the tables are not really related to each other as such, I just to filter the data in both so my dashboard updates both charts. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a table that just has the list of unique countries and make a relationship from that table to both other tables. Then use that table for your filter, rather than the country column of either of the two original tables.

Comment: Thanks. I did this and added it to the page level filter and it worked :)