# Filter multiple tables on single dateTime filter using powerbi

Tags: database, dataframe, powerbi

I'm trying to filter with single common **date** filter multiple tables using powerbi. I'm using postgres RDS engine with powerbi.
What i need is

- Filter 4 tables with single dateTime filter.

**PS. Each table has own date column**

My schema looks like.

> **Table1**
>
> t_id| Date
>
> **Table2**
>
> t_id| Date
>
> **Table3**
>
> t_id| Date
>
> **Table4**
>
> t_id| Date

Comment: Refer this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227345/filter-two-tables-using-the-same-filter-in-powerbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a date dimension table, with relationships to the date fields in your tables. Then you can filter this common calendar table and the filter will be reapplied through these relationships.

You can create your own calendar table, or combine the dates from all 4 tables to get a list of all date values ([merge queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-shape-and-combine-data#combine-data)), or use DAX function like [CALENDAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calendar-function-dax) or [CALENDARAUTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calendarauto-function-dax) to [create such table](https://radacad.com/creating-calendar-table-in-power-bi-using-dax-functions). It is a good idea to [mark it as date table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-date-tables).

Then add `one to many` relationships between this calendar table and date columns of your tables (calendar table on the `one` side).

Add a slicer with the date field from the calendar table, or report level filter on it, depending on your preferences, to filter on it.